# SQLAlchemy-Continuum how to make changes made in many-to-many relationship present in changeset

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-continuum

I'm trying to track changes in many-to-many relationship using `SQLAlchemy-Continuum` package.

Unfortunately only changes made to simple fields like `db.String` are present in the [changeset](https://sqlalchemy-continuum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/version_objects.html#changeset).

How to make changes made to relationship fields present in the `changeset`?

There are some fragments in the docs concerning many-to-many relationships but the documentation lacks examples. https://sqlalchemy-continuum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#sqlalchemy_continuum.relationship_builder.RelationshipBuilder.build_association_version_tables

Any help and examples will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered versioning the model on the other side of the relationship? This way the changes will show up under the transaction associated with a changeset. Unfortunately, `build_association_version_tables` won't help. It is used internally in the relation builder, to create an intermediate association table where needed.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, and I think I found a solution. What I did was first creating actual classes of the many to many tables:

```
# Many to many relationship for users and accounts
user_account_mapping = Table(
    "user_accounts",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("user_id", ForeignKey("users.id"), primary_key=True),
    Column("account_id", ForeignKey("accounts.id"), primary_key=True),
)

# I added the following class:
class UserAccounts(Base):
    __versioned__ = {}
    __table__ = user_account_mapping
    __mapper_args__ = {"primary_key": [
        user_account_mapping.c.user_id, 
        user_account_mapping.c.account_id
    ]}
```

This way you can actually get the `version_class` of the junction table. In my case, if I add/delete an account, a record is added to the `user_version` table, the `user_accounts` table, but not in the `accounts table` (which makes sense, because we didn't change an account).

For SQLAlchemy Continuum this seems hard to actually join the right tables. I guess it somehow makes sense, because when do you need a version table and when not.

What you can do, is building a query yourself now you can get the version_class of the junction table. Obviously you could write your own query and just perform a SELECT query, but I like to keep using the ORM as much as possible.

A dirty solution:

```
from models.user import User
from models.account import Account
from models.mappings import UserAccounts

versioned_user = version_class(User)
versioned_useraccount = version_class(UserAccount)

results = ( 
    db.query(versioned_user, versioned_useraccount, Account)
        .join(versioned_useraccount, 
              and_(
                    versioned_user.id == versioned_useraccount.user_id,
                    versioned_user.transaction_id == versioned_useraccount.transaction_id,
              )
        )
        .join(Account, versioned_useraccount.account_id == Account.id).all()
)

# Map the results, so we don't have the same user object for each account it contains, 
# but just one per unique user with an "accounts" key which contains a list of all accounts.
user_account_mapping = {}
for versioned_user, versioned_useraccount, account in results:
    if versioned_user.transaction_id not in user_account_mapping:
        user_account_mapping[versioned_user.transaction_id] = {}
        user_account_mapping[versioned_user.transaction_id]["user"] = versioned_user
        user_account_mapping[versioned_user.transaction_id]["accounts"] = []

    user_account_mapping[versioned_user.transaction_id]["accounts"].append({
        "id": versioned_useraccount.user_id,
        "operation_type": versioned_useraccount.operation_type,
        "name": account.name
    })
```